# Programmatically determining the cause of IOException?

Tags: java, file-io

Is there any way to programmatically differentiate between what caused an IOException? For example Java will throw an IOException, if there was an error during writing. How can I tell, if it's something like access violation, if the Disk is out of free space, if someone disconnected the the network drive, or other things?

I can't really parse the Message since, there does not seem to be any standardized message format, Sun (or Oracle now I guess) doesn't seem to have any sort of standardized format.

(I need to use Java to fix a very broken system at work.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately Java has no equivalent of .NET's `System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetHRForException()`.  You tell what kind of I/O error it was only if the exception is an instance of a subclass, e.g. `FileNotFoundException`.

Comment: It may not be what i wanted to hear =( but you did answer me.

Answer (score 0):

Getting a hold of the exception's exact class will give you one of a handful of possible subclasses of IOException, and these are quite standardized. You can either test classes with `instanceof` or (a brutish approach) compare strings returned from `getClass().getName()`.

There are some workarounds for the other stuff; you can do a `File.canWrite()` on a file you're about to open for writing (well, your program should have done that anyway, if the name and/or directory can vary), and if there's a chance you ran out of file space, you could try writing a small file to a known good location and seeing if that explodes on you. Not very elegant, I know: Java is not really known as a systems programming language.

On the other hand, very often knowing a detailed cause for an exception doesn't help much: With or without the knowledge, your user may simply not be able to get the program to do what's needed.

Comment: A possible addendum to your first paragraph - usually you're `catch`-ing these exceptions, so a nicer alternative is to have separate catch blocks for `FileNotFoundException`, `UnknownHostException`, etc.  It avoids "explicit" testing and lets you handle the special cases in different blocks from the start (without precluding a catch-all `catch (IOException e)` block at the end).

Comment: @Ahdrzej: You're very right. I was thinking of band-aid fixes to pre-existing coding and assuming uberjumper didn't want to re-arrange the existing catch hierarchies (whatever there may be). But if "doing it right" is an option, then your way would be it.